# What does (UIApplication *)application mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to Objective-C and iPhone Development and while I am familiar with pointers to an extent, I often see code that includes things like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application...
```

When you have the * inside the ( ) like that what does that mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a instance method (`-` means instance method, `+` is class method) that returns `BOOL` named `application` and it takes an argument of a pointer to `UIApplication` named `application`.

The `(UIApplication *)` just means a pointer to a `UIApplication` class.

Comment: Darth, thanks for being thoughtful and explaining this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax is used to declare the argument type. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html for a really good tutorial on Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a pointer-to-`UIApplication` type. The type of the argument is `UIApplication *` is all.